# Ruby on Rails 6 - Dropdown menu created but it is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating an Art Gallery app and drop down menu is not working. The toggle is created.
This is my navbar code in application.html.erb:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <% Category.all.each do |category|%>
                 <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:category] == category.name %>">
                   <%= link_to category.name, paintings_path(category: category.name), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

I am using Bootstrap-sass gem and the code in my application.js is:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");

import "bootstrap";
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

//= require_tree

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

I think there is something about JS and it is not identifying my menu but I am wondering why. Can you please help me with this?
Thanks :)